# how to create a policy of ec2 cloudformation with instancetype t2.micro

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a policy where some user can lauch instance with amid:ami-0fc61db8544a617ed specific and instancetype:t2.micro in a specific region with specific storage like 8gb
I have this template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
    Description: ---
      Policita para usuarios test
    Parameters:
      GroupTest1Parameter:
        Type: String
        Default: GroupTest1
        Description: Este es el valor de entrada GroupTest1Parameter
    Resources:
      PolictyTest1:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
        Properties:
          PolicyName: PolictyTest1
          Groups:
            - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${GroupTest1Parameter}-VPCID"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ec2:RunInstances'
                  - 'cloudformation:Describe*'
                  - 'cloudformation:List*'
                  - 'cloudformation:Get*'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*'
                # Condition:
                #   StringEquals: 
                #     ec2:ImageType: ami-0fc61db8544a617ed
    Outputs:
      PolictyTest1:
        Description: politica que deniega
        Value: !Ref PolictyTest1
        Export:
          Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-VPCID"
```

But it does not work. The template creates fine, but when I am trying to test te policy by using a user test related to this policy, he can not lauch instances of ec2 
I am reading
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-actions-as-permissions

Comment: `t2.micro` is not available in newer regions like `eu-north-1`, `ap-east-1`, `me-south-1`, and `us-gov-east-1`

Comment: I am not asking about t2.micro where is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your scenario, I did the following:

- Created an IAM User
- Assigned this in-line policy to the user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

(Where `ACCOUNT` was set to my AWS Account ID.)

I was then able to successfully launch a `t2.micro` instance using:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxx --security-group-id sg-xxx --instance-type t2.micro
```

I tried changing it to `t2.nano` and received a `UnauthorizedOperation` error.

Please note that the above `run-instances` command was quite minimal. It intentionally did not attempt to specify things like:

- IAM Role
- Tags
- Keypair

These items require granting of additional permissions to the user. Therefore, when testing your policy, use a minimal set of requirements (similar to the above) to test the policy.

Comment: as I described, I want that policy for all users that have that policy. Can I use arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/* instead of arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:subnet/*?

Comment: also that does not work if I want to launch a wizzard

Comment: What do you mean by "launch a wizard"? If this is a requirement, please add it to your question.