# ec2 launch instance policy cloud formation error

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a policy with permission to launch wizard of ec2 from web and cloudformation with specific imageid, type instance t2.micro for any user that have the policy associated. I need to create ec2 instance by using web browser launching wizzard or cloudformation(I said this before) no aws cli, I did not say that before

I have this template

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ---
  Policita para usuarios test
Parameters:
  GroupTest1Parameter:
    Type: String
    Default: GroupTest1
    Description: Este es el valor de entrada GroupTest1Parameter
Resources:
  PolictyTest1:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: PolictyTest1
      Groups:
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${GroupTest1Parameter}-VPCID"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - ec2:DescribeInstances
              - ec2:DescribeImages
              - ec2:DescribeKeyPairs
              - ec2:DescribeVpcs
              - ec2:DescribeSubnets
              - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
              - ec2:CreateSecurityGroup
              - ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress
              - ec2:CreateKeyPair
            Resource: '*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ec2:RunInstances
            Resource: 
              - arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:network-interface/*
              - arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:volume/*
              - arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:key-pair/*
              - arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:security-group/*
              - arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:subnet/*
              - arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1::image/ami-*
              - arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:instance/*
           - Effect: Allow
             Action: ec2:RunInstances
             Resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:instance/*
             Condition: 
               StringEquals:
                 ec2:InstanceType": t2.micro     
Outputs:
  PolictyTest1:
    Description: politica que deniega
    Value: !Ref PolictyTest1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-VPCID"
```

I am using this as a ref od aws doc
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html

but when I try to launch a wizzard from a user that uses that policy I get this error

```
You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: (encripted code)
Hide launch log
Creating security groups

Successful (sg-918298001)
Authorizing inbound rules

Successful
Initiating launches

FailureRetry
```

what am I missing?
I figured out when I have

Action: ec2:RunInstances
Resource: '*'

everythig works fine, but when I set the specified resources I get the error as I mentioned bellow.

I am trying to follow this example

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
         "ec2:DescribeInstances", 
         "ec2:DescribeImages", 
         "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs", 
         "ec2:CreateKeyPair", 
         "ec2:DescribeVpcs", 
         "ec2:DescribeSubnets", 
         "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups", 
         "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup", 
         "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
   },
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action":"ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1:111122223333:network-interface/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1:111122223333:volume/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1:111122223333:key-pair/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1:111122223333:security-group/*",
         "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1:111122223333:subnet/subnet-1a2b3c4d"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1:111122223333:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [ 
            "arn:aws:ec2:sa-east-1::image/ami-*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:Owner": "amazon"
         }
      }
   }
   ]
}
```

that it's from
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html

(Restrict access to specific instance type, subnet, and Region)

Comment: Have you [decoded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html) the `Encoded authorization failure message:` you are getting? May provide more info on what's happening.

Comment: Yeah. I have tried to decode the code. but I got nothing. The system does not say if that it's base 64 or what in order to decode

Comment: As per [amazon ec2 - how to create a policy of ec2 cloudformation with instancetype t2.micro - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61070012/how-to-create-a-policy-of-ec2-cloudformation-with-instancetype-t2-micro), the above permissions are not sufficient if additional parameters are requested, such as tags, an IAM Role or a Keypair. Are any of these being specified?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to launch a wizard from a user"?

Comment: I mean: when I give the permission to the user  from the policy, there is a user that has this policy, so if the user try to launch the wizard from web, he can launch it acording with the permissions

Comment: with the policy created trying to create an ec2 from aws cli does not work for me. Just launching from the web or if the user try to create an instance ec2 from cloudformation, I want that the policy avoid the creation of ec2 if it is not t2.micro from the web and cloudformation